# Is there a way to prevent fetching when `refetch` method get called? react-query

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api, react-query

I have custom fetching hook which uses `useQuery` - from react-query. How can I prevent fetching/refetching based on the `boolean` prop I provide.
At the moment I am using `{ enabled: allowedToFetch }` but this doesn't prevent from fetching when I use `refetch` method from react-query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is per design that `refetch` returned from `useQuery` performs an unconditional fetch and even bypasses `enabled`.

This is very well documented here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries

This is necessary so that you can opt-out of smart refetching and go into "manual" mode by setting `enabled: false` and using `refetch()`.

`queryClient.refetchQueries` and `queryClient.invalidateQueries` respects `enabled`, as do all the smart refetches.

The question is: Why do you have a disabled query where you call `refetch` on but do *not* want it to actually refetch? What's the use case?

if the condition is: `enabled: allowedToFetch`, I would either:

.) wrap the refetch call in the same condition:

```
if (allowedToFetch) {
  refetch()
}
```

.) or use local state to drive the query (the preferred solution):

```
const [allowedToFetch, setAllowedToFetch] = useState(false)

useQuery(key, fn, { enabled: allowedToFetch })
```

now all you need to do to get a refetch is to call:

```
setAllowedToFetch(true)
```

this will enable the query and react-query will do the rest.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in some places when component is rendered I call refetch every 10 sec to keep the page updated as some background processing data is happening. my `allowedToFetch` is false initially, and at some point it sets to true. so while `allowedToFetch` is false and my component renders it would not fetch, but after 10 sec when it calls refetch method it refetches even if `allowedToFetch` is false - but I understand why, I was just wondering what is the best solution in this case.

Comment: When I use my custom hook with `useQuery` and prop` allowedToFetch` is false initially - and I use it as `enabled: allowedToFetch`, but then it switches to true, will it automatically start fetching ? as I look at documentation I see that query keys use as dep array but not options...

Comment: yes, it will, because enabling a query will trigger a refetch. For the refetch every 10 seconds: Why not use the `refetchInterval` option from the query?

Comment: Because logic was in place before I switched to react-query, and not every component where I use my custom hook requires refetching..  so as I understand I have two options: do the check `if (allowedToFetch) { refetch()}` in place where I call `refetch` method or add extra property to my hook which will accept ms or false.